# Python: How to efficiently check if sequence is almost increasing

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

The goal of the code is to see if a sequence is almost increasing, that is, it can be made strictly increasing by removing a single element.

For example: `[1, 3, 2, 3]` would be strictly increasing if the element at index 1 were removed. `[1, 2, 1, 2]` is not almost increasing because if you removed the first '2', you would get `[1, 1, 2]` which is not *strictly* increasing.

My code has to work in under 4000 ms for a sequence of length `2 <= len <= 10^5`. It is likely getting caught up on very long sequences.

Here is the code:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        c = sequence.pop(i)
        if sequence == sorted(sequence):
            for item in sequence:
                if sequence.count(item) != 1:
                    break
            else:
                return True
        sequence.insert(i, c)
    return False
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Can you show some inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: whatever it is looks like an abomination.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, indeed it is.

Comment: Typically problems like this are not about optimizing code. They are about finding "correct" algorithm, with lowest complexity needed to solve given problem.

Comment: It looks like it takes a list, then it removes each element in turn and sees if the resulting list is sorted and contains no duplicates, if that's true then success otherwise add the item back in and try the next element

Comment: @NickA You're correct, see my edit

Comment: @Ryan see my edit

Comment: @AChampion see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for "almost increasing" can be rephrased with the following two rules:

1. There is at most one location `i` in the list that does not satisfy `ai < ai+1`.
2. The elements around the location satisfy the condition `ai < ai+2`.

This is a problem that can easily be evaluated in `O(n)` time:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    iterator = iter(sequence)
    prev = next(iterator)
    found = False
    for item in iterator:
        if item <= prev:
            if found:
                return False
            found = True
        else:
            prev = item
    return True
```

If you are allowed to use numpy:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    ind = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(sequence) <= 0)
    if len(ind) > 1:
        return False
    elif len(ind) == 0:
        return True
    elif ind[0] == 0 or ind[0] == len(sequence) - 2:
        return True
    return sequence[ind[0] + 2] > sequence[ind[0]]
```

The selection tree is for clarity. It can be rewritten as a single return statement:

```
return len(ind) == 0 or \
           (len(ind) == 1 and (ind[0] == 0 or \
                               ind[0] == len(sequence) - 2 or \
                               sequence[ind[0] + 2] > sequence[ind[0]]))
```

Both of these solutions react correctly to edge cases like `[6, 5, 6, 7]` and `[1, 2, 3, 1]`.

Comment: This  (first one) is not working for input [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6]

Comment: @soumya-kole. I wrote this a very long time ago. Thank you for the catch. The numpy implementation had problems too. All the implementations should work reasonably well now.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference of neighboring elements in `sequence` and find out how often it doesn't increase (i.e. how often the difference is not positive):

```
def almost_increasing(seq):
    if type(seq)==type([]):
        seq = np.array(seq)
    diff = seq[1:] - seq[:-1]  # differences of neighboring elements
    indices = np.where(diff <= 0)[0]
    if len(indices) == 0: return True  # increasing sequence, case 1
    elif len(indices) == 1 and indices[0] == len(seq) - 2: return True  # non-increase only at last element, case 2
    elif len(indices) == 1 and indices[0] == len(seq) - 1 and seq[-3] < seq[-1]: return True  # non-increase only at forelast element, case 3
    elif len(indices) == 1 and seq[indices[0]-1] < seq[indices[0]+1]: return True  # case 4
    elif len(indices) == 1 and seq[indices[0]] < seq[indices[0]+2]: return True  # case 5
    else: return False

# For understanding, maybe insert print(indices)
print(almost_increasing([1,2,3]))  # case 1
print(almost_increasing([1,2,3,4,1]))  # case 2
print(almost_increasing([1,2,3,1,4]))  # case 3
print(almost_increasing([1,3,2,3]))  # case 4
print(almost_increasing([1,2,1,4]))  # case 5
print(almost_increasing([1,2,1,2]))

# performance
import time
start = time.clock()
almost_increasing(np.random.random(100000))
stop = time.clock()
print(stop-start)
```

Cases 4 and 5 differ in the choice of the element that is dropped from the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

It would be great if you provided some tests :p but I tried something taking advantage that it's important to look after consecutiveness when size is above 3. Only need to differentiate the list and make sure that n-3 are ones. Hope I'm not mistaking

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def ais(sequence):
    if len(sequence) < 3:  # trivial cases for length 1 and 2 
        return True
    if len(sequence)==3:  # can afford a lazy look
        for perm in itertools.permutations(sequence):
            if perm[1:][1]-perm[1:][0] == 1:
                return True
        return False
    else:
        return list(np.diff(sequence)).count(1) == (len(sequence)-3)
```